# making a tic-tac-toe game in python and not getting the right output [ CLOSED ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-development

```
import random

SELECTION_Y = 0
SELECTION_X = 0

TURN = 1

SPACES = [
        ' ',' ',' ',#2
        ' ',' ',' ',#5
        ' ',' ',' ' #8
        ]

BOARD = ' ' + SPACES[0] + ' ║ ' + SPACES[1] + ' ║ ' + SPACES[2] + '\n' + '═══' + '╬' + '═══' + '╬' + '═══' + '\n' + ' ' + SPACES[3] + ' ║ ' + SPACES[4] + ' ║ ' + SPACES[5] + '\n' + '═══' + '╬' + '═══' + '╬' + '═══' + '\n' + ' ' + SPACES[6] + ' ║ ' + SPACES[7] + ' ║ ' + SPACES[8]

RUNNING = True

while RUNNING:

    print('\n\n\n\n\n\n' + BOARD)
    user = input('P' + str(TURN) + ': ')
    
    if TURN == 1:
        if SPACES[int(user)] == ' ':
            SPACES[int(user)] = 'O'
            TURN = 2
        else:
            print()
    
    if TURN == 2:
        if SPACES[int(user)] == ' ':
            SPACES[int(user)] = 'X'
            TURN = 1
        else:
            print()
```

I tried to make a tic-tac-toe game in python but except when I choose a square it dosent change it to an X or a O.

how the game works is you select a square by typing in 0-8 to choose what square. 0 being the first square and 8 being the last square

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

You're not updating your `BOARD` variable after you change the `SPACES` variable. Try this:

```
import random

SELECTION_Y = 0
SELECTION_X = 0

TURN = 1

SPACES = [
        ' ',' ',' ',#2
        ' ',' ',' ',#5
        ' ',' ',' ' #8
        ]

RUNNING = True

while RUNNING:
    BOARD = ' ' + SPACES[0] + ' ║ ' + SPACES[1] + ' ║ ' + SPACES[2] + '\n' + '═══' + '╬' + '═══' + '╬' + '═══' + '\n' + ' ' + SPACES[3] + ' ║ ' + SPACES[4] + ' ║ ' + SPACES[5] + '\n' + '═══' + '╬' + '═══' + '╬' + '═══' + '\n' + ' ' + SPACES[6] + ' ║ ' + SPACES[7] + ' ║ ' + SPACES[8]
    print('\n\n\n\n\n\n' + BOARD)
    user = input('P' + str(TURN) + ': ')
    
    if TURN == 1:
        if SPACES[int(user)] == ' ':
            SPACES[int(user)] = 'O'
            TURN = 2
        else:
            print()
    
    if TURN == 2:
        if SPACES[int(user)] == ' ':
            SPACES[int(user)] = 'X'
            TURN = 1
        else:
            print()
```